# read.csv("http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=SPY") Not Working

Tags: r, csv, yahoo-api, yahoo-finance, read.csv

I have been using the following command for a long time without problem:

```
spy <- read.csv("http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=SPY")
```

But in the past few days it started to throw the following error:

> Warning messages:
>
> 1: In file(file, "rt") :
>     "internal" method cannot handle https redirection to: 'https://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=SPY'
>
> 2: In file(file, "rt") : "internal" method failed, so trying "libcurl"

I've updated my RStudio, R and all packages to the most up-to-date versions as of today. Could someone help me resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just change url from *http* to *https*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fix is *right there* in the error message: use *https* not http:

```
R> spy <- read.csv("https://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=SPY")
R> head(spy)
        Date   Open   High    Low  Close   Volume Adj.Close
1 2017-04-19 234.52 234.95 233.18 233.44 66861500    233.44
2 2017-04-18 233.72 234.49 233.08 233.87 80188300    233.87
3 2017-04-17 233.11 234.57 232.88 234.57 63559500    234.57
4 2017-04-13 233.64 234.49 232.51 232.51 83019800    232.51
5 2017-04-12 234.74 234.96 233.77 234.03 76322100    234.03
6 2017-04-11 234.90 235.18 233.34 235.06 85727700    235.06
R>
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem -- a few packages just made that change this week too.

Comment: Update the package as the fix is in.

Comment: It's broken now.

Comment: From the _server_ side. Little we can do, sadly.

Answer (score 1):

Yahoo stoped service if you want to run  with small dataset download csv from here and use

> https://github.com/datasets/s-and-p-500-companies

Answer (score 0):

And if you are using the function `getReturns` from the `stockPortfolio` package, use the modified `getReturns` function in the link below:

https://gist.github.com/Maiae/46a058243819ae0973fd38708a32fc31

It basically replaces http:// with https://