# The ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv no longer working

Tags: yahoo-finance

I tried to use both http and https as suggested by [read.csv("http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=SPY") Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43529918/read-csvhttp-ichart-finance-yahoo-com-table-csvs-spy-not-working?answertab=active#tab-top). But none of both are working.

Comment: I found out the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44057580/yahoo-finance-api-changes-2017?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

The service is discontinued, read https://forums.yahoo.net/t5/Yahoo-Finance-help/Is-Yahoo-Finance-API-broken/td-p/250503

The Yahoo finance is now downloading historical data from https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/ using authorization token.