# Python - yahoo finance automatically download

Tags: python, yahoo-finance

I am trying to run the code from here:

[Download history stock prices automatically from yahoo finance in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12433076/download-history-stock-prices-automatically-from-yahoo-finance-in-python)

```
import urllib

base_url = "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s="
def make_url(ticker_symbol):
    return base_url + ticker_symbol

output_path = "C:/Users/test/Desktop/research/stock_data/test"
def make_filename(ticker_symbol, directory="S&P"):
    return output_path + "/" + directory + "/" + ticker_symbol + ".csv"

def pull_historical_data(ticker_symbol, directory="S&P"):
    try:
        urllib.urlretrieve(make_url(ticker_symbol), make_filename(ticker_symbol, directory))
    except urllib.ContentTooShortError as e:
        outfile = open(make_filename(ticker_symbol, directory), "w")
        outfile.write(e.content)
        outfile.close()




pull_historical_data('AAPL', directory="S&P")
```

But I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'ContentTooShortError'
```

How can I make it work? Or can you point me to some code that works?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to import 'urllib.request' and not urllib and update your code as per below.

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve(make_url(ticker_symbol), make_filename(ticker_symbol, directory))

except urllib.request.ContentTooShortError as e:
```

```
import urllib.request

base_url = "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s="
def make_url(ticker_symbol):
    return base_url + ticker_symbol

output_path = "C:/Users/test/Desktop/research/stock_data/test"
def make_filename(ticker_symbol, directory="S&P"):
    return output_path + "/" + directory + "/" + ticker_symbol + ".csv"

def pull_historical_data(ticker_symbol, directory="S&P"):
    try:
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(make_url(ticker_symbol), make_filename(ticker_symbol, directory))
    except urllib.request.ContentTooShortError as e:
        outfile = open(make_filename(ticker_symbol, directory), "w")
        outfile.write(e.content)
        outfile.close()

pull_historical_data('AAPL', directory="S&P")
```

Comment: I get `HTTPError: Proxy Authentication Required`

Comment: seems like you're behind a proxy, you'll need to add the follow code to 
authenticate through the proxy.  





proxy = urllib.request.ProxyHandler({'http': r'http://username:password@url:port'})  

auth = urllib.request.HTTPBasicAuthHandler()  

opener = urllib.request.build_opener(proxy, auth, urllib.request.HTTPHandler)  

urllib.request.install_opener(opener)  

conn = urllib.request.urlopen(make_url(ticker_symbol))  

return_str = conn.read()

Comment: Can you edit your reply in the post above because I don't understand what I need to change

Comment: Not sure whether you are aware, the ichart service has been discontinued since 2017 (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44361361/the-ichart-finance-yahoo-com-table-csv-no-longer-working). I got a weird error message when running the code, so tried to visit the above page and got a "This site can’t be reached" message.